# Digitally sign email in Ruby with S/MIME

Tags: ruby, email, openssl, digital-signature, smime

Is there a way in Ruby to digitally sign email messages with S/MIME?  Our group uses PKI and our users are conditioned to expect digital signatures for important messages.

I know I can invoke the openssl command line tool:

```
openssl smime -sign -signer $CERT_FILE -passin pass:$CERT_PASS
  -in $UNSIGNED_MAIL -out $SIGNED_MAIL -certfile $CERT_CA_FILE
  -from 'your ' -to 'recipients <email@address>'
  -subject 'The Subject'
```

but I am hoping to utilize a Ruby solution.

Comment: I ended up using the above solution, but for those in a similar situation, you have to convert the PKI key (in .p12 file format) first: openssl pkcs12 -in #{@cert_file} -passin pass:#{@pass_phrase} -passout pass:#{@pass_phrase} -out #{out_file}

Comment: I can't believe the amount of (working) code examples I get when I google "ruby smime"... That's... impressive!

Comment: here's a stack overflow with someone who says they figured out how to do it. I don't understand what's going on enough to know how far this gets you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159478/openssl-smime-in-ruby-rails

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @padde I didn't have enough reputation to do that when I first posted the question, but I do now--thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the above solution, but for those in a similar situation, you have to convert the PKI key (in .p12 file format) first: `openssl pkcs12 -in #{@cert_file} -passin pass:#{@pass_phrase} -passout pass:#{@pass_phrase} -out #{out_file}`